# calculate a running time of a function

Tags: performance, scheme, big-o

I have trouble with coming up the running time of a function which calls other functions. For example, here is a function that convert the binary tree to a list:

```
(define (tree->list-1 tree)
  (if (null? tree)
  ’()
  (append (tree->list-1 (left-branch tree))
          (cons (entry tree)
          (tree->list-1 (right-branch tree))))))
```

The explanation is T(n) = 2*T(n/2) + O(n/2) because procedure append takes linear time.  Solving above equation, we get T(n) = O(n * log n).

However, the cons is also a procedure that combines two element. In this case it goes though all the entry node, why don't we add another O(n) in the solution?

Thank you for any help.

Comment: O(n*log(n) + n)  = O(n*log(n))

Answer (score 1):

Consider `O(n^2)` which is clearly quadratic.
Now consider `O(n^2 + n)`, this still is quadratic, hence we can reduce this to `O(n^2)` as the `+ n` is not significant (it does not change the *"order of magnitude"* (not sure this is the right term)).

The same applies here so we can reduce `O([n*log(n)] + n)` to `O(n*log(n))`. However we may not reduce this to `O(log(n))` as this would be logarithmic, which is not.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you are asking about the difference between `append` and `cons`.

The time used by `(cons a b)` does not depend on the values of `a` and `b`. The call allocates some memory, tags it with a type tag ("pair") and stores pointers to the values a and b in the pair.

Compare this to `(append xs ys)`. Here `append` needs to make a *new* list consisting of the elements in both `xs` and `ys`. This means that if `xs` is a list of `n` elements, then `append` needs to allocate `n` new pairs to hold the elements of `xs`.

In short: `append` needs to copy the elements in `xs` and thus the time is proportional to the length of `xs`. The function `cons` uses the time no matter what arguments it is called with.